# network manager not show bond0 lacp connection

Tags: networking, network-manager, network-bonding, systemd-networkd

System is running Ubuntu desktop 23.04

I am unable to update Application Software because the application does not see a network connection.

I have created a LACP 802.3ad dual nic connection using the netplan config file and renderer networkd.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      #renderer: NetworkManager
      ethernets:
        enp4s0:
          link-local: [ ipv4 ]
          dhcp4: no
          # dhcp6: no
        enp5s0:
          link-local: [ ipv4 ]
          dhcp4: no
          # dhcp6: no
      bonds:
        bond0:
          addresses: [192.168.2.10/24]
          interfaces: [enp4s0,enp5s0]
          link-local: [ ipv4 ]
          routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.2.1
              metric: 100
          nameservers:
            addresses: [192.168.2.1]
          parameters:
            mode: 802.3ad
            transmit-hash-policy: layer3+4
            lacp-rate: fast
            mii-monitor-interval: 100
```

The configuration works properly:

```
$ ip adress show
    1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
        inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    2: enp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 62:19:71:3d:05:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr d8:bb:c1:9b:1d:89
    3: enp5s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 62:19:71:3d:05:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff permaddr d8:bb:c1:9b:1d:8a
    4: wlo1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 8c:1d:96:da:8b:bc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        altname wlp0s20f3
    5: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
        link/ether 62:19:71:3d:05:c9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
        inet 192.168.2.10/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global bond0
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   $
```

But when I access network manager the network configuration is not shown:
[image: Network manager configuration]

I have tried changing the render from networkd to NetworkManager by the changing which renerder line is commented out in 01-netcfg.yaml.  When I change the render to NetworkManager, the bond0 gets an incorrect ip address and the default gateway is no longer accessible.  The example below was made by changing the renderer to NetworkManager in the yaml file, then issued netplan apply and rebooted the system.

[image: Network Manager post netplan change and reboot]

[image: Network manager with renderer NetworkManager]

I am OK without using NetworkManager, but I need to be able to install and update applications.  Application update shows there is no valid network connection despite having a valid public internet connection (internet browsing works, as well as Ubuntu Software Updater).  I assume application software update is broken because network manager doesn't show a network connection.  I don't use wifi on this system, so it is disabled.

[image: Application Software update app]

Ubuntu Software Updater works properly:

[image: Ubuntu Software Updater]